# Как добавить круг в правом верхнем углу кнопки над фоном кнопки и за её рамкой?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я хочу добиться следующего результата с помощью CSS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, в основном я хочу, чтобы круг был поверх background кнопки, но находился  за её границей.
С помощью следующего кода я могу нарисовать аналогичную кнопку:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -21px;
  right: -21px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #4da6ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button
        <span class="circle"></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Проблема здесь в том, что круг находится над кнопкой, но также и над ее границей.

Необходимо сделать так, как показано на рис. ниже :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to add a circle on the top right corner of a button above the background and behind the border?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58700523/7394871) от участника  [@Shaunyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2726467/shaunyl).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58700523/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Для SVG это тривиальная задача. Нужно только разместить элементы в правильном порядке:

1. Нижний слой - прямоугольник с текстом.
2. Выше синий кружок
3. Поверх рамка
   Это аналогично решению в CSS с псевдоэлементами  для создание рамки

   `button::after {border: 2px solid black;}`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="160" height="70" viewBox="0 0 160 70"  >  
    
    <rect  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"  fill="#EFEFEF" stroke="black" />
     <text x="70" y="54" text-anchor="middle" font-size="21px"  fill="black"> Test Button </text>  
       <circle cx="135" cy="26" r="18" fill="#4DA6FF" />
        <rect  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Можно немного усложнить задачу, чтобы получить вокруг синего круга белую границу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого необходимо создать элемент маски - повторяющий нижнюю половину синего круга с широкой строкой.

```
<mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
         <path fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" d="M117,26 A18,18 0 0 0 153,26" />
</mask>
```

- Эта маска при окраске полуокружности в черный цвет, прорезает фон
  серого прямоугольника и показывает нижнюю часть окружности.
- Широкая строка полуокружности `stroke-width="10"`, тоже прорезает фон
  прямоугольника, но в этом месте под фоном ничего нет, поэтому
  получается белая окантовка вокруг синей окружности.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="160" height="70" viewBox="0 0 160 70"  >  
 <defs>
   <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
         <path fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" d="M117,26 A18,18 0 0 0 153,26" />
   </mask>
</defs> 
  
      <circle cx="135" cy="26" r="18" fill="#4DA6FF" />
    <rect mask="url(#mask)"  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"  fill="#D0D0D0" stroke="black" />
     <text x="70" y="54" text-anchor="middle" font-size="21px"  fill="black"> Test Button </text> 
        <rect  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
    
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

*Вариант с тёмной темой, радиальным градиентом, анимация фокуса градиента*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<animate attributeName="fy" dur="0.5s" begin="svg1.mouseover" 
restart="whenNotactive" values="25%;75%" fill="freeze"   />
```

Анимация фокуса градиента `fy` (белое пятно) начнется после наведения курсора

```css
.container {
 width:30vw;
 hight:30vh;
 background:#151515;
 }
 #c1 {
 fill:url(#Rg2);
 }
 #svg1:hover   circle#c1 {
 fill:url(#Rg1);
 }
 .rect {
 fill:#D0D0D0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 160 70"  >  
 <defs>
   <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
         <path fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" d="M117,26 A18,18 0 0 0 153,26" />
   </mask> 
   <radialGradient id="Rg1"  fx="25%" fy="25%" r="50%" >
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="white"/>
       <stop offset="1" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
         <animate attributeName="fy" dur="0.5s" begin="svg1.mouseover" restart="whenNotactive" values="25%;75%" fill="freeze"   /> 
   </radialGradient> 
    <radialGradient id="Rg2"  fx="25%" fy="25%" r="80%" >
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="white"/>
       <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
  
      <circle  id="c1" cx="135" cy="26" r="18"  />
     
     <rect class="rect" mask="url(#mask)"  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"   pointer-events="none" />
      <text x="70" y="54" text-anchor="middle" font-size="21px"  fill="black"> Test Button </text>  
         <rect  x="5" y="26" width="130" height="40"  fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" /> 
    
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: Я уже начал беспокоиться, где, думаю, SVG...))

Answer (score 4):

Одна из идей - интегрировать недостающие границы внутри круга.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform:translate(50%,-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(black,black) left  /50% 2px,
   linear-gradient(black,black) bottom/2px 50%,
   #4da6ff;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

Или вы можете просто рассмотреть режим `mix-blend-mode`. Обратите внимание на используемое значение, так как оно будет зависеть от сочетания цветов. В этом случае подходящий затемняется.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform:translate(50%,-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4da6ff;
  mix-blend-mode:darken;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

Третий способ более интересный с использованием только фонов:

```css
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border:0 solid transparent;
  border-top-width:24px;
  border-right-width:24px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background:
     linear-gradient(black,black) top   /100% 2px,
     linear-gradient(black,black) bottom/100% 2px,
     linear-gradient(black,black) left  /2px 100%,
     linear-gradient(black,black) right /2px 100%,
     radial-gradient(circle, #4da6ff 19px,transparent 20px) left bottom/200% 200% padding-box border-box,
     #e2e2e6 padding-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

Другой вариант - разместить круг за элементом и вырезать фон:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  position: relative;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at top right,transparent 19px,#e2e2e6 20px);
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  transform:translate(50%,-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#4da6ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700914/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Это не похоже на коленвал... И на шатун тоже)) Хочу похвастаться как я поженил SVG и Canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69789529/12656388 . Вот и до меня докатились dasharray))

Comment: @Leonid так переводи вопрос-ответ и делай ассоциацию. Он стоит того! И я тогда, попробую ответить здесь

Comment: Я так не умею, я даже не понял толком что он хочет))) Но зато мне захотелось попробовать dasharray в canvas. Долго я тыркался. Оказалось, что отрицательное значение почему-то должно быть, а в массив передавать именно отрезок больше чем длина пути надо и больше ничего. Или я не правильно что-то тыркал. В SVG какая логика этих всех смещений за счет пунктиров?

Comment: @Leonid Если тебе нужно стирать линию, то проще воспользоваться stroke-dashoffset/  Устанавливаешь сначала в атрибутах stroke-dashoffset ="0" stroke-dasharray="1000" Это максимальная длина линии - 1000px/  затем увеличиваешь stroke-dashoffset от нуля до 1000. Этим самым будет стираться линия.

Comment: Ясно, а в canvas оказалось, что надо отрицательные значения в качестве offset давать. Значит логика та же. Спасибо.

Comment: @Leonid Избегай отрицательных значений. В safari это не работает. так что лучше сразу привыкать. Проще начни рисовать с другого конца и тогда не нужны будут отрицательные значения. Либо надо удваивать stroke-dashoffset, чтобы избежать отрицательных значений

Comment: Я же про CanvasRenderingContext2D.lineDashOffset, на сайте MDN так тоже используется. При этом отступ именно от начала идет. Для SVG по-другому, видимо.

Comment: @Leonid MDN для FF и Chrome в safari отрицательные значения не работают, встречал вопросы на EnSO, ответ там был - пошлите запрос в баг репорт Хотя за canvas в safari не уверен, может быть и работают отрицательные значения

Comment: Если честно, то не люблю я зоопарк от яблока, они сейчас как IE в свое время, я же даже возможности не имею проверить если у меня компа нет с грызаным плодом розоцветных)) Пусть берут нормальные телефоны и компьютеры))) Понты корявые

Comment: @Leonid и я того же мнения ((( Главное эмулятора бесплатного подходящего для IOS не найду, не в смысле размера экрана, а именно для тестирования функциональности приложения

Comment: Я устанавливал на VirtualBox MacOS, хотя писали, что сложно и плохо работает. Нормально все встало. Как и что уже толком не помню. Вроде дистрибутив на рутрэкере качал...

Answer (score 3):

Используйте псевдоэлемент (:: after), чтобы нарисовать границу над кругом:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #4da6ff;
  content: '';
}

button::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700592/7394871) от участника  [@Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori).</sub>